# Load program to one side of monitor in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer, shortcuts

This is a question to enhance the feature on Windows 7, where you drag the screen to one side and it docks to that side of the screen.

Is there a way to have it so when I load a program, it knows that I always like it docked on the right side, so it just loads on the right side? And I don't have to drag it to the right.

It will be done for Internet Explorer, so, if there is no setting on the Shortcut for this, can it be programmed into the browser?

Comment: I don't know of any way to do this baked in, but there's probably 3rd party software that can handle it.  I'd just point out that if you prefer there are keyboard shortcuts for this - Winkey+LeftArrow and Winkey+Rightarrow.

Comment: Yeap, I found out about the shortcuts, and also about AutoHotKey ( Very cool program). Just wondering if there was a way to do it naturally within Windows.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't actually mash the window against the side of the display, and instead resize it manually to approximately occupy that area, then close internet explorer, it will be in the same place the next time you restart. When you mash a window against a side of the screen, that position and size is not saved when you exit, likewise with maximizing, so you need to resize it yourself. Once you do that, it will remember in the future, unless you move it again then close it.

Comment: I know about this method. Still wondering if there is an automatic docking.